# Can I Use Yellow Split Peas in Paruppu Urundai instead of Toor Dal

Tags: substitutions

I thought toor dal (thoor dal?) was the Hindi term for the pigeon pea (Cajanus cajan).  Additionally I thought yellow lentils (Lens esculenta) and split yellow peas (Pisum sativum) were two different plants.  Bit confused.

Which brings me to my most important question – if I wanted to make Paruppu Urundai could I substitute split yellow peas for the toor dal?  I live in a small, rural town and although our health food is store is brilliant we don’t have a huge range of choices.

Answer (score 1):

Paruppu Urandai, is a Tamilian (Iyengar/South Indian) Recipe. It uses Thuvara or Tur Dal (Arhar Dal). Now substituting Tur Dal with Yellow Peas, wouldn't be right choice.
Tur has a special flavour, which is retained even after it turns to Cereal or Cooked. But the Pea looses its flavour when it turns to Cereal, it turns tasteless.
So Tur's unique flavour that is retained even after cooking impacts the overall flavour of dish.